# How to deploy web service along with a windows application installation?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a multi tier windows application. one of the layers is implemented using web services and the UI layer communicate with this layer. I want to make an installation package for the application and i need the installation package to deploy the web services to the local machine's IIS during the installation, so the user doesn't need to go to IIS and configure it manually.

Comment: And what you have tried and why it failed?

Comment: I have tried nothing! i've no idea on how to do this! could it be done using custom action? can i add a .cmd file to the installation to do the iss config? i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can package your Web Service (or any web application) as a *Web Deploy Package*.

See this link on how to do this from Visual Studio: https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-publish-with-web-deploy-package

Such a package also comes with a .cmd file that could be run by your setup. Read the deploy-readme.txt alongside it to learn more.